# X number of arguments passing to a rake task

Tags: ruby, rake

I just wonder how to have dynamic (X) number of arguments passing to a rake task.
for example I want to achieve this:

> rake task:test[arg1,arg2,arg3,...]

So here the number of arguments are not fixed, it could be `arg1..arg10` or `arg1..arg20` or maybe less/more than this.

any idea?

P.S: I don't want to waste too much memory for this task, thus I'm looking for an optimal solution. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-define a maximum number of parameters, but you don't need to use all:

```
require 'rake'
myargs = 'p1'.upto('p20').map{ |x| x.to_sym }

task :test, myargs do |t, args|
  puts "#{t}: #{args.inspect}"
end

Rake.application[:test].invoke(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

The result:

```
test: {:p1=>1, :p2=>2, :p3=>3, :p4=>4, :p5=>5, :p6=>6, :p7=>7, :p8=>8}
```

If you need default values, you can define them:

```
task :test, myargs do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:p19 => 'default1')
  puts "#{t}: #{args.inspect}"
end
```

Result:

```
test: {:p19=>"default1", :p1=>1, :p2=>2, :p3=>3, :p4=>4, :p5=>5, :p6=>6, :p7=>7, :p8=>8}
```

Another way to define parameters witth default values:

```
myargs = Hash.new{|hash,key| hash[key] = "Default #{key}"}
20.times{|i| myargs[:"p#{i}"] }

task :test, myargs.keys do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(myargs)
  puts "#{t}: #{args.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so the question is that I don't want to limit the number of arguments; may have more than 20 e.g; 1 - 100XX arguments, so If I have : `myargs = 'p1'.upto('p10000').map{ |x| x.to_sym }` then this will reserve a lot of memory..

Comment: Yes, but be honest: When you call the task via `rake mytask[1,2,...100000]`, how will you do it with 10000 parameters?

Comment: Yeah, but for sure I may have more than 20 arguments, and this task will be invoked randomly. Anyway I up voted your answer. Currently its the only right solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need this, but here is my solution:

```
task :test, [:arg] do |t,args|
   arguments = Array.new
   arguments << args.arg
   args.extras.each{|a| arguments << a}
   puts arguments
end
```

Result:

```
rake test[arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,...]
arg1
arg2
arg3
arg4
...
```

Comment: Nice to know that args.extras exists.  For brevity, the sample task code could also be shortened to one single line: `puts [args.arg] + args.extras`